# Avast: NVIDIA Virtual Audio 3.40.1 удален(а) не полностью

Tags: nvidia

Аваст отличается удивительно скупыми сообщениями, не позволяющими принять решение.

Вот такое сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать?

**UPDATE**

Я ничего не начинал удалять, я вообще отходил от компьютера, а когда пришёл, это сообщение висит на экране. Можно предположить, что это Аваст решил, что программа плохая, стал её удалять, но удалил не полностью. Другой вариант -- что кто-то пытался удалить программу, но удалил не полностью.

В любом случае, подобные сообщения приходится игнорировать, так как нет абсолютно никакого понятия, что они означают.

Comment: в зависимости от того, что вам нужно.. но если уже начали удалять, то доделайте руками, то что не доделал avast

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в техподдержку производителя софта.

Comment: @kff угу, раз kff не знает ответа, значит, вопрос нужно удалить, как же иначе?

Comment: @Dims Прочитайте причину закрытия внимательнее. Если есть проблемы с пониманием, прочитайте ещё раз.

Comment: @kff это не у меня проблемы с пониманием, а у Вас, очевидно; причина закрытия мне совершенно понятна (перечитайте её несколько раз, если угодно); среди Ваших вопросов я нашёл с десяток, которые можно было бы адресовать производителю какого-либо софта, так что не расстраивайтесь за меня

Answer (score 0):

Если проблема(из-за которой пришлось удалять) осталась - лучше почистить всё самому с помощью сторонних утилит типа "ccleaner" и ей подобных.
Если проблемы нету - то, как полагается, антивирус доочистит всё после перезагрузки. Либо же антивирус оставил файлы, которые кассаются Вас(то есть те, которые Вы сами создали). Такие файлы не несут вреда системе и могут быть оставлены или удалены самостоятельно.